# New Firestore rules release

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Question to Firebasers: the [page listing the Firestore rules release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/security-rules) shows a new release as of July 8th 2021 but the notes are missing

[image]

Do you know whether there is actually a new release or it is an error of the release page?

Note: I have raised a ticket to Firebase about 3 weeks ago but I am just very curious as of what could be new...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*firebaser here*

Thanks for reporting, and I can't believe we didn't catch that obvious mistake.

The update was about the new ability to inspect requests made to Firestore in the emulator UI, which is a neat new way to debug your security rules during development. Check out
this [blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2021/08/firestore-emulator-requests-monitor.html)
for more details.

We also updated the page of course, so if you still see the include code - be sure to force a refresh (cmd-R/ctrl-F5).